# Django redirect() shortcut not working anymore?

Tags: python, django

If to redirect in the view like:

```
@secure_required
def school_index(request, school_id):

    school = get_object_or_404(School, pk = school_id)    
    redirect('schools:school_events', kwargs= {'school_id': school.id} )
```

then I get the Error:

```
 Request Method:    GET Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8008/schools/20/
 Django Version:    1.9.6 Exception Type:   NoReverseMatch Exception
 Value: 
 Reverse for 'school_events' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'kwargs': {'school_id': 20}}' not found. 
1 pattern(s) tried:['schools/(?P<school_id>\\d+)/events/$']
```

Urls:

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^(?P<school_id>\d+)/$', views.school_index, name='school_index'),
    url(r'^(?P<school_id>\d+)/events/$', views.school_events, name='school_events'),
]
```

As I undestand, redirect() is just a shortcut which should return the HttpResponseRedirect for a given object, url or a view. I provide correct name of the view, keyword argument but Django cannot match the url. What can be wrong?

P.S. Everything is working fine if to use HttpResponseRedirect:

```
@secure_required
def school_index(request, school_id):

    school = get_object_or_404(School, pk = school_id)
    url = reverse('schools:school_events', kwargs= {'school_id': school.id})
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Comment: Does your url pattern really have double slash for the `\\d+`?

Comment: try `redirect('schools:school_events', school_id=school.id)`, [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)

Comment: @devxplorer if to redirect like that I get ValueError: The view schools.views.school_index didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: @Sayse I have posted my urls in the question

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov - If that resolved the redirect then the second issue is because your first snippet doesn't return the redirect

Comment: return redirect('schools:school_events', school_id=school.id)

Comment: @Sayse yes, true. your answer is correct. Post it and I will mark it a correct one. P.S. Actually @devxplorer)

Comment: Its not really my answer, It would be better if @devxplorer would like to make their comment an answer.

Comment: @devxplorer true, please post your answer)